# How to count chars in input(form)

Tags: meteor

I'm need to count user input length in simple form.
I'm tried this:

```
Template.index.created ->
    @symbols = new ReactiveVar
    @symbols.set($('#whatsnew').val().length)
    return
```

And in template(jade):

```
//index.jade
.small-9.columns
  input(type='text', placeholder='whats new?', name='whatsnew', id='whatsnew')
...
#{sybmols}
...
```

But this not working
I'm need to count characters of user input. How to make it?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `$('whatsnew').val().length`? Your question/problem is not well formed.

Comment: please provide more code , so that it can help others as well who face the same sort of issue

Comment: added. @below9k, this not working ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't reactive. There's no reason for your ReactiveVar to rerun. You can try adding an event for every onkeyup event in your input field. When this happens you can get the length of the entered text and set it in your symbols ReactiveVar.
Then every reatice context dependent on symbols will rerun.